# Mysql select from 2 different tables and merge result

Tags: mysql, join, merge

I'd like to ask you for help with mysql. I want to merge 2 absolutely different tables which has date column. Tables looks like that:

Tab1:

```
NAMECOLUMN   |      DATECOLUMN
------------------------------
itemname1    |      2013-01-01
itemname2    |      2013-02-02
itemname3    |      2012-04-01
```

Tab2:

```
OTHERCOLUMN  |      DATECOLUMN
------------------------------
xyz         |      2013-01-31
abcd        |      2013-01-02
efgh        |      2012-03-01
```

and I'd like to have result ordered by time:

```
OTHERCOLUMN |      NAMECOLUMN      DATECOLUMN
---------------------------------------------
(null)      |      itemname1       2013-01-01
xyz         |      (null)          2013-01-31
abcd        |      (null)          2013-01-02
(null)      |      itemname2       2013-02-02
efgh        |      (null)          2012-03-01
(null)      |      itemname3       2012-04-01
```

Thank you for showing me way :)

Comment: How do you see result record(s) for records with similar date in DATECOLUMN in both tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT NULL AS othercolumn, NAMECOLUMN, datecolumn
  FROM tab1      
  UNION
  SELECT otherColumn, NULL, dateColumn
  FROM tab2
  ) a
ORDER BY datecolumn
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c5a5/4)</kbd>

EDIT:

As per your new table3, you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT NULL as otherColumn, t1.NAMECOLUMN, t3.category,t3.type, t1.datecolumn
  FROM tab1 t1      
  INNER JOIN tab3 t3 ON t1.tab3id = t3.id
  UNION
  SELECT otherColumn, NULL,NULL,NULL, dateColumn
  FROM tab2
  ) a
ORDER BY datecolumn;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3feab/4)</kbd>

Comment: Good use of union +1 i was also posting the same but bit late :)

Comment: Dear Filipe, I updated sqlfiddle and I have also third table (which I didn't mention before :) ) Could you pls. help me finish it? :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3feab/1/0

Comment: @FredericoRossini. This third table has a different structure. How do you want to relate it to the other tables?

Comment: tab1 should point to that tab3, it means tab1.TAB3ID = tab3.ID

Comment: so you want to have tab3.category and type in the rows that are from tab1 and null for tab2 in those columns?

Comment: yes, in fact, I'd like to have 1row with results (* from tab1+tab3) and tab2 on separate row.

Comment: @FredericoRossini. i edited my answer. see if that is what you want.

Comment: this is absolutely what I need! It works and I thank you @FilipeSilva. How ever there is small "performance issue" -> tab1 has around 500000 rows, tab2 around 30000 and tab3 also 30000. It takes 27sec on local to get 10rows (LIMIT 10 at the end of query). Where should I put LIMIT to get only 10results (in better time).

Comment: If you want 10 items from each part, you can use ORDER BY the way you want and then LIMIT 10 inside: `... LIMIT 10
  UNION...` and then `...FROM tab2 LIMIT 10`

Comment: now I am totally satisfied :) Thanky you very much @FilipeSilva and enjoy weekend :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
SELECT namecolumn, othercolumn, t2.datecolumn
FROM Tab1 t1, Tab2 t2;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

> select  null as OTHERCOLUMN,NAMECOLUMN ,DATECOLUMN    FROM Tab1
>
> UNION
>
> select OTHERCOLUMN,null as NAMECOLUMN,DATECOLUMN FROM Tab2